# How can I use PHP to sort a two dimensional array?

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort the array below by 'name'. I have tried several things but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array('name'=>'Bill','phone'=>'555-5555');
$data[] = array('name'=>'Joe','phone'=>'555-5554');
...
```

Comment: *what* have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281841/how-do-i-sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-value?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `usort()` to sort an array using a custom criteria.

For instance:

```
function my_sort_by_name($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

$data = array();
$data[] = array('name'=>'Bill','phone'=>'555-5555');
$data[] = array('name'=>'Joe','phone'=>'555-5554');
usort($data, 'my_sort_by_name');
```