# How do I sort a multi-dimensional array ascending and descending?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, php-7

I have an array as following and I want to order that array ascending and descending  by the value of the key "min_price". I tried and I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281841/how-do-i-sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)  still not working properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the array:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [property_id] => 116 
                [min_price] => 3487
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [property_id] => 131
                [min_price] => 3035
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [property_id] => 171
                [min_price] => 7999
            )
    )

      function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['min_price'] == $b['min_price']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['min_price'] < $b['min_price']) ? -1 : 1;
} 
uasort($data, 'cmp');
```

I want to use this array ascending and descending order.

Comment: What specifically did you try from the referenced question?

Comment: @MichaelSacket i use this function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['attack'] == $b['attack']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['attack'] < $b['attack']) ? -1 : 1;
} 

uasort($data, 'cmp');

Comment: You'll need to replace the key `attack` with `min_price`.

Comment: @MichaelSacket i replaced key attack with min_price but still not working

Comment: Ok @dhanashri, I figured, but I didn't want to assume.  Can you update the question with the code you're using?

Comment: @dhanashri : try this :
`usort($Array, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['min_price']==$b['min_price']) return 0;
    return $a['min_price'] < $b['min_price']?1:-1;
});`

Comment: @prakashtank Thanks working fine... :)

Comment: @dhanashri : glad it worked !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new Combined Comparison Operator(AKA [Spaceship](http://www.php.net/language.operators.comparison)) (Since php-7):

```
// Integers
echo 1 <=> 1; // 0
echo 1 <=> 2; // -1
echo 2 <=> 1; // 1
```

More info in the [announcement](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator).

So you could write:

```
usort($Array, function($a, $b) {
                                 return $a['min_price'] <=> $b['min_price']; 
                               });
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of sorting

```
<?php
  $array = array(
  0 =>array(
      'name' => 'Rnukir',
      'total' => '1'),
  1 => array(
      'name' => 'Arnesista',
      'total' => '2'),
  2 => array(
      'name' => 'Omas',
      'total' => '3'),
  3 => array(
      'name' => 'John',
      'total' => '4')
);
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $name[$key]  = $row['name'];
    $total[$key] = $row['total'];
}
 print_r($total);

 array_multisort($total, SORT_DESC, $array);
//  array_multisort($total, SORT_DESC, $name, SORT_ASC $array);
echo "<pre>";
  print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```