# Sort multidimensional associative array by values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this set of array:

```
Array(
    [day_1] => Array(
        [3744] => Array(
            [time_start] => 11:00
            [time_end] => 12:00
            [notes] => 
        )
        [3746] => Array(
            [time_start] => 08:00
            [time_end] => 11:00
            [notes] => 
        )
        [532] => Array(
            [time_start] => 09:00
            [time_end] => 11:30
            [notes] => 
        )
    )
    [day_2] => Array(
        [3747] => Array(
            [time_start] => 08:00
            [time_end] => 10:00
            [notes] => 
        )
    )
)
```

How do I sort the array in "day_1" based on the value of "time_start"?

The end result that I want to achieve is:

```
Array(
    [day_1] => Array(
        [3746] => Array(
            [time_start] => 08:00
            [time_end] => 11:00
            [notes] => 
        )
        [532] => Array(
            [time_start] => 09:00
            [time_end] => 11:30
            [notes] => 
        )
        [3744] => Array(
            [time_start] => 11:00
            [time_end] => 12:00
            [notes] => 
        )
    )
    [day_2] => Array(
        [3747] => Array(
            [time_start] => 08:00
            [time_end] => 10:00
            [notes] => 
        )
    )
)
```

I have tried:

```
foreach($array['day_1'] as $key => $value){
    $starttime[$key] = strtotime($value['time_start']);
}
array_multisort($starttime, SORT_ASC, $array['day_1']);
```

But its not sorted and it removes my array key as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multi-dimensional array by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281841/how-do-i-sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution using [***uasort***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function:

```
// $arr is your initial array
uasort($arr['day_1'], function($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a['time_start'], $b['time_start']);
});

print_r($arr);
```

[***Demo link***](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e46e59e5be42d8da2bee9a38c4fb60751b38601d)